# Firebase: How to query by key?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a locations table that I want to query. The key is "050PNS74ZW8XZ".

[image]

As you can see, it exists.

However, when I print out any attributes it doesn't work

```
function testing(req, resp) {
  const location = database.ref('locations').equalTo('050PNS74ZW8XZ');
  console.log('location:', location.account_capabilities); // <--- prints undefined
  resp.json("asfdsf");
}
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you know the key, you can use the `child` method.

However, the more fundamental problem is that the value is not directly available from the ref. You can obtain the value using the `once` method - to listen for the `value` event - which returns a promise that resolves to a snapshot:

```
function testing(req, resp, next) {
  database.ref('locations').child('050PNS74ZW8XZ')
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      console.log('location:', value.account_capabilities);
      resp.json(value.account_capabilities);
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

There is more information in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Answer (score 2):

if you know the key you can access the child directly, then turn it into a object with $firebaseObject.

```
var locref = database.ref('locations').child('050PNS74ZW8XZ');
const location = $firebaseObject(locref);
```

the equalTo function should be used when querying from a list.

Comment: That is because 'location' is a firebase ref not a object. you will have to use $firebaseobject

Comment: is that a method on the firebase ref?

Comment: I'm sorry I gave a angular solution, cartant's solution is for pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
const location = database.ref('locations/050PNS74ZW8XZ');
```